# Left Outer Join in Linq to Entities / SQL

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How can I write the following SQL in LINQ to Entities?

```
SELECT r.rolename,
       ( CASE
           WHEN ur.username IS NULL THEN 0
           ELSE 1
         END ) AS isinrole
FROM   bgt.roles r
       LEFT OUTER JOIN bgt.usersinroles ur
         ON ur.rolename = r.rolename
            AND ur.username = 'ADMIN'
```

Comment: var query = from r in Roles
join ur in UsersInRoles on new {f1 = r.Rolename, f2 = 'ADMIN'}
equals new {f1 = ur.Rolename, f2 = ur.Username} into temp
from x in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { f1 = r.RoleName, f2 = x.Username };

Comment: I heard DefaultIfEmpty is not supported in EF. Is it true?

Comment: `DefaultIfEmpty` is supported since EF 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me. Thanks for all the suggestions.

```
var query = 
from r in Roles
from ur in UsersInRoles
.Where(v => v.Rolename == r.Rolename && v.Username == "ADMIN")
.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { Rolename = r.Rolename, IsInRole = (ur.Username != null) };
```

The generated SQL is as follows

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[Rolename] AS [Rolename], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Username] IS NOT NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ([Extent2].[Username] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C2]
FROM  [bgt].[Roles] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [bgt].[UsersInRoles] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[Rolename] = [Extent1].[Rolename]) AND ('ADMIN' = [Extent2].[Username])
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
from role in db.Roles
let isInRole = role.UsersInRoles.Any(u => u.UserName == "ADMIN")
select new { role.RoleName, isInRole }
```

Althought the generated SQL is not as nice as yours.

Comment: Thanks you put me in the right direction. Settled for the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Extension method for Left join (linq to entities):

```
            public static class DbSetExtensions
            {
                public static IQueryable<TResult2> LeftJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult2>(
                    this IQueryable<TOuter> outerList,
                    IEnumerable<TInner> innerList,
                    Expression<Func<TOuter, TKey>> outerKeySelector,
                    Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>> innerKeySelector,
                    Expression<Func<LeftJoinTemp<TOuter, TInner>, TInner, TResult2>> resultSelector2)
                {
                    // (tr, historicPrices) => new { tr, historicPrices }
                    Expression<Func<TOuter, IEnumerable<TInner>, LeftJoinTemp<TOuter, TInner>>> myResultSelector1
                        = (tr, historicPrices) => new LeftJoinTemp<TOuter, TInner> { outer = tr, inners = historicPrices };

                    // e => e.historicPrices.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    Expression<Func<LeftJoinTemp<TOuter, TInner>, IEnumerable<TInner>>> myCollectionSelector
                        = e => e.inners.DefaultIfEmpty();

                    //var a = outerList.GroupJoin(innerList, outerKeySelector, innerKeySelector, resultSelector1);
                    var a = outerList.GroupJoin(innerList, outerKeySelector, innerKeySelector, myResultSelector1);

                    //return a.SelectMany(collectionSelector, resultSelector2);
                    var b = a.SelectMany(myCollectionSelector, resultSelector2);
                    return b;
                }
            }

            public class LeftJoinTemp<TOuter, TInner>
            {
                public TOuter outer;
                public IEnumerable<TInner> inners;
            }
```

example calling, left join of Transaction and HistoricPrice, for transaction you have to write parent.outer

```
            .LeftJoin(db.HistoricPrices,
                transaction => new { transaction.InstrumentId, DateId = transaction.Date2Id },
                historicPrice => new { historicPrice.InstrumentId, historicPrice.DateId },
                (parent, historicPrice) => new
                {
                    parent.outer.Id,    
                    parent.outer.OpeningDate,
                    parent.outer.InstrumentName,
                    historicPrice.DateId,
                    historicPrice.InstrumentId
                })
```